# Compact operators on Banach spaces and their spectra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory

I have a question about compact operators on Banach spaces.

Let $B$ be a real Banach space and $L$ a closed linear operator on $B$.
We assume that $L$ generates a contraction semigroup $\{T_t\}_{t>0}$ on $B$ .

**If $B$ is a Hilbert space** and $L$ is self-adjoint, the following assertions are equivalent:

(1) The spectrum of $L$ is discrete (the essential spectrum $\sigma_{ess}(L)=\emptyset$).

(2) $T_t$ is compact for any $t>0$.

(3) $T_t$ is compact for some $t>0$.

(4) $R_{\lambda}:=(\lambda-L)^{-1}$ is compact for any $\lambda \in \rho(L)$.

(5) $R_{\lambda}$ is compact for some $\lambda \in \rho(L)$.

Here, $\rho(L)$ is the resolvent set of $L$.

Even if $B$ is not a Hilbert space, (2)$\Rightarrow$(4), (4)$\Leftrightarrow$(5), (5)$\Rightarrow$(1).

**My question**

In what follows, we further assume that $\{T_t\}_{t>0}$ is strongly continuous and $B$ is a $L^1$ space on a measure space.

Does (1)$\Rightarrow$(5) hold? or

**Under what conditions, does (1)$\Rightarrow$(5) hold?**

By the way, I am particularly interested in situations where $\{T_t\}_{t>0}$ is generated by a **symmetric** Markov process on a locally compact metric measure space $(X,\mu)$. In this case, for each $1\le p <\infty$, $\{T_t\}_{t>0}$ is extended to a strongly continuous contraction semigroup $\{T_t^p\}_{t>0}$ on $L^{p}(X,\mu)$ and it holds that  $T_t^p f=T_tf$ for any $t>0$ and $f \in L^{1}(X,\mu) \cap L^{p}(X,\mu)$.

Comment: Why on earth would (1) and (5) be equivalent even in a Hilbert space? The identity operator has discrete spectrum...

Comment: (2) and (3) also not equivalent, there are eventually compact semigroups (e.g. nilpotent shift)

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to assume $L$ is self-adjoint.

Comment: Even for self-adjoint $L$ on a Hilbert space, (1) does not imply (5): As @AndrásBátkai wrote, the identity operator has discrete spectrum. But probably you mean something else by (1) than the spectrum being discrete as a topological space?

Comment: In my definition, the spectrum of $L$ is discrete iff the essential spectrum of $L$ is empty set...

Comment: Under this definition also the above statements are wrong?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification; I suggest to include it in the question. By the way, if you include "@JohnDoe" in a comment, then John Doe is notified about the comment; this is very helpful if you reply to comments of other users (while the author of a post is always notified about new comments to their post).

Comment: @JohnDoe I understood.

Comment: @sharpe I don't think you did ...

Comment: @JochenGlueck I understood.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The essential spectrum (and even the spectrum) of the generator of a contractive $C_0$-semigroup on an $L^1$-space can be empty even if the generator does not have compact resolvent.

**Example.** Endow $[0,1]^2$ with the Lebesgue measure and define a $C_0$-semigroup $(T_t)_{t \ge 0}$ on $L^1([0,1]^2)$ by
\begin{align*}
  (T_tf)(x,y) = 
  \begin{cases}
    f(x+t,y) \quad & \text{if } x+t\le 1, \\
    0 \quad & \text{if } x+t>1
  \end{cases}
\end{align*}
for all $f \in L^1([0,1]^2)$ and all times $t \ge 0$. Then $(T_t)_{t \ge 0}$ is nilpotent (since $T_t = 0$ for $t \ge 1$), so the generator of the semigroup has empty spectrum; in particular, the generator has empty essential spectrum.

However, the resolvent of the generator is not compact (this follows from the fact that the semigroup action is trivial along the $y$-axis).

**Remark.** I'm not sure whether there is a natural set of additional assumptions which make the implication (1) $\Rightarrow$ (5) true on $L^1$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. By the way, under what conditions, the implication (1) $\Rightarrow$(5) holds? I would appreciate it if you let me know.

Comment: @sharpe: My apologies, the wording in my final remark was not well chosen. What I actually wanted to say is that there might be some sufficient conditions, but (a) if so, then I do not know about them and (b) it is questionable whether such conditions would be fulfilled in the applications that you have in mind (which seem to be related to Markov processes). I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply.